# Returning an IList<GenericClass> property in another class

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-list

I have an `ErrorMessage` class and `ResultMessage` class that need to be generic. The `ErrorMessage` is:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public int httpStatus { get; set; } 
    public string Header { get; set; } = "Error";
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

The `ResultMessage` is the same as the `ErrorMessage`, except it must also return an `IList` result, meaning that for example if I inserted a user successfully, the output should be

```
{
 "httpStatus": 200,
 "Header" : "Success",
 "Message" : "User added Successfully",
 "Result" : {
 "userName": "dfdaadf",
 "password": "faeferafreaf"
}
}
```

My `ResultMessage` is:

```
public class ResultMessage : ErrorMessage
{
    public ResultMessage()
    {
        httpStatus = 200;
        Header = "Success";
    }
    public virtual IList<T> Result { get; set; }
}
```

where `T` should be defined as a generic class to be used for example as:

```
var msg = new ResultMessage();
var user = new User();
var list = new IList<User>();
list.Add(user);
msg.Result = list;
```

Ofcourse `public virtual IList<T> Result { get; set; }` is wrong syntax.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Maybe also think about your inheritance: Is a `ResultMessage` an `ErrorMessage` or is an `ErrorMessage` a `ResultMessage`? Since `ResultMessage` statically has httpStatus 200 it's for sure no `ErrorMessage`. Your inheritance seems to be fishy.
IMHO you should have a class `ResultMessage` which is inherited by `SuccessMessage` (code 200). And have `ErrorMessage`, which also inherits `ResultMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ResultMessage` has also to be generic:

```
public class ResultMessage<T> : ErrorMessage
```

When calling it has to be something like this:

```
var msg = new ResultMessage<User>();
var user = new User();
var list = new List<User>();
list.Add(user);
msg.Result = list;
```

Another hint:

List properties shouldn't be settable. Either use a readonly interface for this property like `IReadOnlyList<T>` or make the property itself readonly and initialize it on construction:

```
public class ResultMessage<T> : ErrorMessage
{
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Result { get; set; }

    public IList<T> Result { get; } = new List<T>();
}
```

Comment: Or use methods they can have their own generic definition eg. `void SetResult<T>(IList<T> result)` | `IList<T> GetResult()`

Answer (score 0):

List implements IList interface, you could ResultMessage as a generic class, example:

```
  public class ResultMessage<T> : ErrorMessage
    {
        public ResultMessage()
        {
            httpStatus = 200;
            Header = "Success";
            Result = new List<T>();
        }
        public virtual IList<T> Result { get; set; }
    }



var msg = new ResultMessage<User>();
            var user = new User();
            msg.Result.Add(user);
```